# how to limit display or height of a select HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder if their's a way to limit the display or height of a select tag.

This is an image of what I want it to look like

[image: http://i192.photobucket.com/albums/z73/shut2kill/1-4_zpsa7388db7.png]

I don't mind if it's Javascript, Jquery, CSS, or make it just a list
I need to know on. how to do this.
or could give me a sample.

Comment: Browser controls that.

Comment: Do you need it to have specific height or you just want to limit number of visible options? If later then just use `size` attribute `<select size="7">` (as in your screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

If you will end up needing to style the select dropdown even a little, I suggest looking for jQuery plugins. I use [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) but I'll warn you now, it's a pain to do anything with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     <select size="5">
```

or what ever the size you want : hope this works for you